# Rails Product Name In Views

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am presently building a rails project with meal menu. 
I have some trouble to display the product_name from my DB.Right now it's displaying multiple btn with all my product name but I just wan't one btn with their respective names.
I know it's a noob question but im stock on this problem.
Here's what it look lke right now:
[My menu website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeXQW.png)

Here's my code:

**/app/views/main/_menu.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% (1..8).each do |i| %>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="image-container">
            <img id="menu-image" src="/assets/menu/menu-<%= i %>.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">$9.99</h4>
            <h4>
              <% @products.each do |product| %>
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<%= i %>" style="color:#0B610B;"> 
                  <%= product.product_name %>
                </a>
              <% end %>
            </h4>

            <p>This is the product description</a>.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="ratings">
            <p class="pull-right"> reviews</p>
              <p>
                <%= render "modal_menu" %>
                <% (1..5).each do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-star-o rating-star"></i>
                <% end %>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that the order of the products match the order of the meals (looks like it according to your screenshot) then this could do the trick:

```
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <% if index+1 == i %>
        <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<%= i %>" style="color:#0B610B;">
          <%= product.product_name %>
        </a>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However it would be cleaner to loop over the products directly in the first place instead of (1..8). For example (untested):

```
<div class="row">
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img id="menu-image" src="/assets/menu/menu-<%= index+1 %>.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="pull-right">$9.99</h4>
          <h4>
            <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<%= index+1 %>" style="color:#0B610B;">
              <%= product.product_name %>
            </a>
          </h4>

          <p>This is the product description</a>.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ratings">
          <p class="pull-right"> reviews</p>

          <p>
            <%= render "modal_menu" %>
            <% (1..5).each do %>
                <i class="fa fa-star-o rating-star"></i>
            <% end %>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful and it absolutely worked !!